# combining input name of two names inside input

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, variables

is it possible to input 2 variables inside one input?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answer1[], updateCb[]" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer1']; ?>" />
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answer1[]" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer1']; ?>" />

<input type="checkbox" name="updateCb[]" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer1']; ?>" />
```

how can I combine them?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Why would you need to do this? You can simply assign variables in the server.

Comment: @Barmar you again, i'm very thankful for those of your helps. but is there a way i change the value of the given record with other record?

Comment: meaning this code: <input type="checkbox" name="answer1[]" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer1']; ?>" /> change to <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer2']; ?>" />

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Yes exactly we are unable to understand why are you doing this. can you explain what is your next step . what you want to achieve by this?

Answer (score 1):

```
No it is not possible .
```

But If you want to post multiple value to php and don't want to show in your form then I think you can achieve this by using hidden fields and assign those value.

Comment: do you think they can merge as one value?

Comment: u r welcome, any questions - feel free to ask

Comment: lol :) @qwertmax comment on my thread.

Comment: sorry, wrong window ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do what you ask. How would you imagine to input two separate variables using a single checkbox? If you have two variables that should have the same value you either don't need one of them or can perform some assignment in your code. No need to use a single checkbox to initialize them both.

Comment: ok if that is, i just want to change the value of the given record with other record, what do you think?

Comment: @LacsonCruz I believe you should do that in the server code

Answer (score 1):

if it's possible you can do it on the frontend via javascript (or jQuery)

you can make updateCb as hidden input and fill it by form submit event

```
 <input id="answer1" type="checkbox" name="answer1[]" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer1']; ?>" />
 <input id="updateCb" type="checkbox" name="updateCb[]" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer1']; ?>" />
 <input id="updateCb-id" type="hidden" name="new_val[]" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer1']; ?>" />

 jQuery("form").submit(function(){
      jQuery("input#updateCb-id").val(jQuery("answer1").val() +" "+ jQuery("updateCb").val());      
 });
```

smth like this

Comment: ok tnx for this, im going to try this...

Comment: u r welcome, any questions - feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answer1_update1[]" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer1']; ?>" />
```

It is not possible but you can combine the result of update1 and answer1 in third checkbox